# Request XML brackets are being removed from my Servlet

Tags: java, jsp

I have a jsp and within the `form` tag has the following text area so that I can submit XMLs to a servlet:

```
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <textarea name="xmlreqdoc" rows="20" cols="50"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The text area is where I submit the request XML and I retrieve the submitted XML like the following in my servlet class:

```
String requestXML = pReq.getParameter("xmlreqdoc");
```

Where `pReq` is just `HttpServletRequest`.

---

Now, the issue that I am having is that when I submit an XML through my JSP text area, the `String requestXML` returns back all brackets removed , i.e. `>` and `<` in the XML and I have no idea why?

---

```
    <%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:include page="/common/doctype_html.inc" />
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js" ></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function postXMLToOMV2(){
                        formomv2.submitaction.value="getClientGuid";
                        formomv2.action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/user/create/OMTestClient.do";                        
                        var $form = $('#formomv2');             
                        $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize());


            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <FORM accept-charset="UTF-8" name="formomv2" method="post" action="#" id="formomv2">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h1>Please enter the ECS DM Messaging</h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <textarea name="xmlreqdoc" rows="20" cols="50"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            TransId: <INPUT type="text" name="transId" value=""/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            Encrypted: <INPUT type="checkbox" name="encrypted" value="Y"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="submitRequest" onclick="postXMLToOMV2()"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="hidden" name="submitaction" value="" />
            </FORM>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how are you submitting the form?

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte I have included the form

Comment: you should add the javascript too. @Robin

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte I have add js as well

Comment: check my answer now, let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

The way in which you are submitting your form seems to make it so that certain characters are not being escaped from your XML string. Try [serializing](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serialize.asp) your form before submitting.

Since you're using Jquery, you can try something like this:

```
   function postXMLToOMV2(){

         formomv2.submitaction.value="getClientGuid";
         formomv2.action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/user/create/OMTestClient.do";

         var $form = $('#formomv2');             
         $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize());

         // im not sure where you have declared 'formomv2' but if you have you could probably also just do the following:
         //  $.post(formomv2.attr("action"), formomv2.serialize());

            }
```

Comment: if you want to ajaxify it, let me know and i can edit it for you

Comment: hey jonathon, i have made the suggested updated but i still am having the same issue

Comment: Then you must be changing the string somewhere with more javascript. Please post ALL the javascript.

Comment: dude you need to remove  "formomv2.submit();"

Comment: "$.post(formomv2.attr("action"), formomv2.serialize());" is already submitting your form.

Comment: use the code i have in my answer, exactly, don't change anything. Don't add anything. Tell me what happens when you do that.

Comment: I still got same issue. It removes the brackets still

Comment: very strange, there doesn't seem to be a reason why it is happening with the code you posted. Can you please show your servlet too?